# Can conclude from the values from maximum likelihood estimation.

Tags: estimation

Determine the maximum likelihood estimates of a and λ when X1, ..., Xn is a sample from the Pareto density function
f(x) = λαλχ-(2+1), if x ≥ a
0          ,if x <a
I tried to solve it

The Pareto density function:

[ f(x) = \lambda^n \cdot a^n \lambda \cdot x^{-(\lambda+1)} ]

The logarithm of the likelihood function:

[ \log f = n \log \lambda + n\lambda \log a - (\lambda+1) \sum_{i} \log x_i ]

Taking the derivative with respect to λ and setting it equal to zero:

[ \frac{d \log f}{d \lambda} = 0 ]

Solving for λ:

[ \lambda^* = \frac{n}{\sum_{i} \log x_i} - n \log a ]

Taking the derivative with respect to a and setting it equal to zero:

[ \frac{d \log f}{d a} = 0 ]

We have:

[ \frac{\lambda.n}{a} = 0 ]

Now I'm unable to conclude .